# iOS chat app best logic to send read messages

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating my own chat, now I need to send request about user read messages.
What is the best approach to do this? Messages displayed in UITableView I guess I should use delegate method with visible cells:

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: *"I need to send request about user read messages"* -- we have no idea what that means. Please review [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do in this delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

You may argue why not willDisplayCell?

That is because, the cell will be displayed, but there is no guarantee that the cell will be displayed at all. For example, your app may have experienced crashing, user back pressed, or user may have terminated.

So that is the reason I would suggest `didEndDisplaying`, because already cell displaying end, so here goes your own logic.

Comment: this method doesn't call on initial startup of view controller, only when you did end scroll

Comment: Did you mention that? If you mark it as all read, then just call it in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. Why will you use the delegate method then? My assumption was to decrease the unread count as per as scrolling, the same Telegram does.